# How to check whether request is being served from apache server to tomcat server?

Tags: apache, apache2, tomcat7

I have configured apache2.4.12 server with mod_jk to four instances of tomcat 7.0.47 server and had done the configuration for load balancing also. But I am not sure whether request is being served from apache server or not. I want to check whether request is being served from Apache -> Tomcat -> Apache ? Is tomcat taking request from apache ? Also, after doing configuration i am getting following mod_jk.log :

> [error] ajp_validate::jk_ajp_common.c (2748): worker worker1 can't
>   resolve tomcat address localhost:8009
>
> [error] ajp_validate::jk_ajp_common.c (2748): worker worker2 can't resolve tomcat address localhost:8019
>
> [error] ajp_validate::jk_ajp_common.c (2748): worker worker3 can't resolve tomcat address localhost:8029
>
> [error] ajp_validate::jk_ajp_common.c (2748): worker worker4 can't resolve tomcat address localhost:8039

Answer (score 0):

Check the log files in your tomcat logs directory (it is usually in $CATALINA_HOME/logs), namely localhost_access_log.2015-05-28.txt) and you fill find out.